# ¿Enviar un link entre dispositivos android?

Tags: java, android

Tengo dos dispositivos uno va a compartir internet el otro se va a conectar a la red del dispositivo para entrar a internet. Lo que quiero es enviar información (un link) a los dispositivos que se conectan al android que comparte el internet pero necesito que solo el dispositivo que comparte internet sea el único al que le tenga que programar una aplicación para realizar dicha función. He pensado en algo parecido a los hoteles donde te conectas y cuando abres el explorador te abre una página de autenticación, en mi caso le mostraría la página que quiero.

Como alternativa de que otra manera podría enviarle el link sin usar bluetooth ni tener que preguntar su número de teléfono ni decirle que entre a alguna página especifica.

Comment: Israel, revisa lo que comenta Jose: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

Answer (score 1):

Lo que quieres es programar una aplicacion hotpot, que en su interior venga preconfigurada para tener un [portal cautivo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_cautivo).

Si es el caso, necesitarás de las **Android Wireless APIs**. Te dejare abajo varios Link(s) para que te guies.

Link(s):

[Wi-Fi Peer-to-Peer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html)
Connecting Devices Wirelessly | Android Application Development
www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pEl-Y06Ypo